# AngularJS - ngClick not working on dynamically added html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a simple app in which i have a single input element with a `mylist` model.
If `mylist=1` i ng-include first.html and if `mylist=2` i ng-include second.html. So far so good.

My problem is that in each html template i have a button that when clicked i want to change the value of `mylist` so i can navigate to the other and in order to achieve this i do:

```
<button ng-click="mylist=x" >switch to x</button>
```

but ng-click doesn't work. Why?

Here is my code:

**scripts.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainController',  function ($scope) {

    $scope.mylist = 1;

});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <input type="number" ng-model="mylist" />{{mylist}}
  <br/>
  <div ng-switch on="mylist">

    <div ng-switch-when=1>
      <ng-include src="'first.html'"></ng-include>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when=2>
      <ng-include src="'second.html'"></ng-include>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**first.html**

```
<p>first</p>
<button ng-click="mylist=2" >switch to 2</button>
```

**second.html**

```
<p>second</p>
<button ng-click="mylist=1">switch to 1</button>
```

Also here is the Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/bVATLV66kN21LC8EPeoW

Comment: ng-switch creates a new scope, try ng-click="$parent.mylist=1".

Comment: @ZackArgyle no, it's not working

Comment: $parent.$parent.mylist should work but the answer below is probably better :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ng-include` creates a [child scope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).  So you should [bind to an object property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/1245971) instead of a primitive.

```
$scope.my = {
  list: 1
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/SbeGch5MJdux33HgYsEJ?p=preview